# Sort file as Month name in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, date

I have a directory, it contains files like:

```
january2009.xml, february2009.xml, march2009.xml,april2009.xml,january2010.xml, february2010.xml, march2010.xml,april2010.xml ...
```

I use the `cfdirectory` to get the file by year. Right now, I want to display it as sorted order in month. Say If I only want year 2009 data. I want it sorted as

```
january2009.xml, february2009.xml, march2009.xml,april2009.xml
```

but not

```
april2009.xml, february2009.xml, january2009.xml, march2009.xml
```

Anyone has easy way to do it in ColdFusion?

Comment: Between this and your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857690/) you seem to be asking for someone to do a lot of your work for you and have shown basically no evidence of attempting to do it yourself.

Comment: I am quite new to ColdFusion. But I am definitely not ask someone else do my work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using a QuickSort solution.

http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/9/12/Ask-a-Jedi-Sorting-files-numerically-that-begin-with-strings

Answer (score 5):

I won't provide a solution to your problem, but rather make a suggestion. If it's very important to have these sorted by date, you would be better off using ISO 8601 format in your file naming convention (e.g. 2009-02.xml instead of february2009.xml). Sorting would become very easy.

Answer (score 0):

<cfdirectory directory = "#currentDirectory#" name = "myDirectory" sort = "name ASC, size DESC">

Comment: it won't gonna work, coz you just sort by name. I want to sort by Month.